# List of tables from slick generated schema

Tags: scala, slick

I want to get list of tables from slick generated schema. I saw the there is generated:
`lazy val schema: profile.SchemaDescription = Table1.schema ++ Table2.schema ++ ...`

But I see no way of extracting tables out of it. I could go with `schema.cereateStatements` and filter on `create table`, to extract the table names but it's not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read tables with `MTable` class

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import slick.jdbc.meta.MTable 

//Tables from public schema

    db.run(MTable.getTables(Some(""),Some("public"),Some(""),Some(Seq("TABLE")))).
       onComplete {
           case Success(tables) => println(tables.map(_.name).mkString(" - "))
           case Failure(f) => println(f)
       }
```

The result is:

```
MQName(public.table1) - MQName(public.table2)
```

If you want Indexes too, add `"INDEX"` to Seq

```
Some(Seq("TABLE","INDEX"))
```